# Inputs bug on Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

i have a problem with form inputs on only on safari. I don't know why they stick out beyond the edges of the form.

[image]

Comment: Can you share some code, please?

Answer (score 1):

## Why is this happening

This happens because inputs have a default width determined by the `size` attribute of an input. You can learn more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_size.asp).

#### Workaround

You can adjust the size attribute or make the parent bigger but my favorite way is to create a div that wraps input and its corresponding label, give it a `display: flex`, and a `flex-direction: column`. This way input will always span the full width of the parent. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/9e4uw5yk/17/)

Comment: Couldn't agree more. My answer shows how to scale the input to its parent and it's up to you to scale the parent the way you want.

Comment: Then, it's alright. It is working on chromium, but I don't know if it works on Safari because I don't use Apple.